# What is the equivalent command for Ping

Tags: perl, hp-ux

I am trying to ping a IP on HPUX. I am using the commands

```
ping 15.178.209.120 64 10
```

and

```
ping -c 10 15.178.209.110
```

perl code that i am using is

```
$Ping  = `  ping -c 10 15.178.209.110`;
```

`$ping` is empty.

I tried in HPUX also.
It's not pinging. It's saying command not there.  What is the equivalent command for ping in HPUX

Comment: Google for `ping hpux` gives many answers. Perhaps you need to install it, or give a full path (maybe `/usr/sbin/ping` or something else).

Comment: the command ping itself is unrecognised

Comment: @Nitesh — Basile has given you two approaches that might resolve that.

Comment: This is exactly why Perl contains the Net::Ping module. So that you can write portable code that doesn't rely on external programs that might move (or might not exist) on different platforms.

Comment: @Basile: Thanks. It was the directory issue only. I gave the path alongwith ping. now its workinh. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Net::Ping](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Ping) is a core module in perl. If it is a perl solution you are looking for.

Comment: i tried manually also in hpux. the command ping itself is not recognised

Comment: @Nitesh — So what? As far as I can tell, by skimming the source, Net::Ping uses socket modules and doesn't shell out to call a `ping` binary.

Comment: @Nitesh The command ping in the shell is not the same thing as the Net::Ping module in perl. Perl can solve this task for you.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you have $Ping (capital P) for the external execution and then $ping (lowercase p) which you say is empty.  Could this be your problem?